# Unable to Get a Working Desktop Launcher for a Python Program

Tags: unity, python, launcher

I am building an entirely new Debian package `cpconverter` which is `A simple utility to change the code page of plain text based files`, from a source published in Google Code.

Eveything went fine. However I can't get a working launchpad launcher.

The python file `cpConverter.py` is stored in folder `/usr/share/cpconverter/cpconverter/`.

I have a `Shell Script` named `cpconverter` in folder `/usr/bin/`, which reads:

```
#!/bin/sh

python /usr/share/cpconverter/cpconverter/cpConverter.py
```

The Desktop Launcher `cpconverter.desktop` is simple

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=0.5
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Code Page Converter
Name[en_US]=Code Page Converter
Comment=A simple utility to change the code page of plain text based files
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/bin/cpconverter
Icon=cpconverter
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Categories=Utility;
```

However it fails to start.

I did check that the installed `cpConverter.py` is working fine by launching it:

```
$ python /usr/share/cpconverter/cpconverter/cpConverter.py
```

Then the program is launched on some occasions. After clicking the launcher it often don't work anymore.

However the file `cpConverter.py` in the building structure of the package always works e.g.

```
$ python cpconverter-0.5/debian/cpconverter/usr/share/cpconverter/cpconverter/cpConverter.py
```

I tried to type the same command line from a Terminal and then I got a variety of unheard of errors (at least for me):

```
$ cpconverter
/usr/bin/cpconverter: 3: /usr/bin/cpconverter: pyhton: not found
$ 
$ pyhton /usr/share/cpconverter/cpconverter/cpConverter.py
No command 'pyhton' found, did you mean:
 Command 'python' from package 'python-minimal' (main)
pyhton: command not found
$
```

Then I tried to take a working example for package `convertall` which for its `Shell Script` uses:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/convertall/convertall.py "$@"
```

From the Terminal I would successfully  launch it with:

```
$ python3 /usr/share/convertall/convertall.py "$@"
```

Then I modified the `Shell Script` in accordance to read:

```
exec /usr/bin/python2 /usr/share/cpconverter/cpConverter.py "$@"
```

The result is still the that the Desktop Launcher is not working ... some hourglass and nothing. However, either of these 3 command lines always launch the program:

```
$ python2 /usr/share/cpconverter/cpconverter/cpConverter.py "$@"
$ /usr/bin/cpconverter
$ cpconverter
```

The access rights for the `cpconverter.desktop` are standard:

```
$ ls -l /usr/share/applications/clipgrab.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 626 Dec  9  2014 /usr/share/applications/clipgrab.desktop
```

Why then the Desktop Launcher is unable to launch the program ? What is wrong with my Desktop Launcher ? [See it above]

Comment: FIrst of all it looks like you confused 'pyhton' with 'python' all over. At least the errors from the command line are caused by this.

Comment: Second, why are you using a shell script?. You should just probably use a correct shebang on the python script itself (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang)

Comment: I beg your pardon on what you just said. You are pointing fingers as `"I confused  'python with 'python'"` which is itself close to ridicule ... Do you have any example or specifics on errors I did commit to support your affirmation ? I believe you are just not up to the level.

Comment: Furthermore, the command line `Bash` versions of the `Dash` script are launching the Python script. Then I figure out that there is nothing wrong with the .py file.

Comment: A command line in `Bash` extracting the Exec= field from the Desktop Launcher file is working fine as well.
`$ $(grep '^Exec' /usr/share/applications/cpconverter.desktop | tail -1 | sed 's/^Exec=//' | sed 's/%.//') &`

Comment: Check your own question. The part bellow 'I got a variety of unheard of errors (at least for me):'. About the other questions I'm sorry but I'm not going to waste my time trying to help people with your attitude.

Comment: If you don not have any clues or specifics other than playing with words, it will be better for you to "waste your time" elsewhere ... :-). The fact is you don't have any plausible explanation for the observed behaviour ...

Comment: One more element : Launching the working `Dash Script` from its location (like the desktop launcher do) fails : 
`/usr/bin$ cpconverter `
`Traceback (most recent call last):`
  `File "/usr/share/cpconverter/cpconverter/cpConverter.py", line 342, in <module>`
`    app = cpConverter()`
`  File "/usr/share/cpconverter/cpconverter/cpConverter.py", line 74, in __init__`
`    builder.add_from_file("./gui/gui.xml")`
`glib.GError: Failed to open file './gui/gui.xml': No such file or directory`
`/usr/bin$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as I said in the comment, running the `Dash Script` from the `/usr/bin/` directory just as the desktop launcher is doing, failed with this Python error:

```
/usr/bin$ cpconverter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/cpconverter/cpconverter/cpConverter.py", line 342, in <module>
    app = cpConverter()
  File "/usr/share/cpconverter/cpconverter/cpConverter.py", line 74, in __init__
    builder.add_from_file("./gui/gui.xml")
glib.GError: Failed to open file './gui/gui.xml': No such file or directory
$
```

While running `cpconverter` at the prompt elsewhere in the Home folder or in `/usr/share/cpconverter/cpconverter` (where is coCPnverter.py file is) would succeed.

Then it was obvious that the culprit was the `./` in the `cpConverter.py` file.

I simply created a patch `allow-launch-from-usr-bin-script.patch` to place the absolute path (once packaged) instead of the relative path:

`builder.add_from_file("/usr/share/cpconverter/cpconverter/gui/gui.xml")`

That explained and solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is really necessary, but when I made a bash script I launched the script with this command "bash $$$$$$$.sh". The only reason that I mention this is that the .py extension is not on the script name in your desktop launcher. May be nothing, worth a look and a try.    Craig

Comment: The `Shell Script` I use is not `Bash` but `Dash`. I suggest you update your knowledge on the differences ... Besides, the script is working fine as when I invoke its [partial -- i.e. adapted from Dash to Bash] content in Bash it is working fine, as stated in the question.